# Comparação de string em C

Tags: c, string

Como eu poderia imprimir a variável *sexo* fora do `if-else` (tem que ser FORA dele).

Esse código está imprimindo em branco e não consigo entender o porquê.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");//habilita a acentuação para o português!

        int escolha;
        char sexo;


    printf("Escolha uma das opções abaixo: ");
    printf("\n1- Sou mulher ");
    printf("\n2- Sou homem ");
    scanf("%d", escolha);

    if(escolha==1){
        char sexo[]="Feminino";

    }
    else{
        char sexo[]="Masculino";
    }

    printf("Você é do sexo: ");
    printf(sexo);

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5):

Tem alguns erros no código incluindo de sintaxe. Resolvendo estes problemas e organizando um pouco o código o que precisa saber é o uso da função `strcpy()` para transferir o conteúdo da *string* para o vetor.

Tem maneiras melhores para fazer isto, mas para começar aprender está bom assim.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int escolha;
    char sexo[11];
    printf("Escolha uma das opções abaixo: ");
    printf("\n1- Sou mulher ");
    printf("\n2- Sou homem ");
    scanf("%d", &escolha);
    if (escolha == 1) strcpy(sexo, "Feminino");
    else strcpy(sexo, "Masculino");
    printf("Você é do sexo: %s", sexo);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dqGacn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/imfzaxde-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CopyToArray.c).

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, você está declarando apenas um `char` lá no começo e o usando como um `vetor`, você precisa declarar a quantidade de caracteres que irá usar na declaração dele, você pode fazer uma base de quantos irá usar e colocar lá (com um a mais para ficar o caracter especial `\0` que indica o fim da `"string"`). Segundo, você está apenas igualando vetores de char, e isso não é possível em C, para isso você precisa usar a função `strcpy(vetor de char, string a ser adicionada);`, da uma pesquisada sobre a biblioteca `<string.h>` que lá tem várias funções muito usadas como o `strcmp` que compara strings e outras muito interessantes também.